# How to select only one sibling with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have this code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo">foo text</li>
  <li class="foo2">foo2 text</li>
  <!-- more li here -->
  <li class="bar">bar text</li>
  <li class="bar2">bar2 text</li>
  <!-- more li here -->
  <li class="baz">clickme!</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$(".baz").click(function() {
    alert("test: " + $(this).siblings(".bar")[0].text()); // Doesn't work
});
```

`siblings(".bar")[0]` doesn't work. (no alert box pops up, and no javascript error)

What is the proper way to select one sibling only ?

[jsFiddle try](http://jsfiddle.net/fMT5x/)

**Edit:** I don't want to use `prev()` or `next()`.

Comment: Have a good question badge. This is the only place I could find an example of how to limit the siblings to a particular class.

Comment: @ouflak You're welcome

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to reduce the matched set of elements to one at a specific index:

```
$(this).siblings(".bar").eq(0).text()
```

That will select the first element in the set. In your case, you could simply use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), as the element you're looking for comes directly before the clicked element:

```
$(this).prev(".bar").text()
```

The problem with the array notation method you were using is that it returns the actual DOM node contained within the jQuery object, and that's not going to have a `text` method. `eq` is the equivalent jQuery method to do this.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for `eq()`. Btw, what does it mean ?

Comment: @pinouchon: Read the documentation and find out. James even handed you the link so that you don't have to go to the vast effort of entering `jQuery eq` in Google.

Comment: I'm asking because i didn't find out in the doc.

Comment: @pinouchon - As Tomalak said, I gave you a link the the jQuery docs page in question. And here it is again: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: I meant : what does `eq` stand for ?

Comment: @pinochon - I've always assumed it stands for "equal" but I don't really know if that's correct, and if so, why! I'm guessing something like "get the element at index equals 0".

Answer (score 12):

You can also grab the first element out of a jQuery object using first:

```
alert(siblings(".bar").first().text());
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/next/ and/or http://api.jquery.com/prev/.

So it would be:

`$(this).prev().text());`  or    `$(this).next().text());`

Answer (score 2):

You could use next() or prev();

```
$(".baz").click(function() {
    alert("test: " + $(this).prev(".bar").text());
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fMT5x/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can either do:

```
$(".baz").click(function() {
    alert("test: " + $(this).prev.html());
});
```

BUT, you have to be sure that a previous item exists to .baz

OR (Better)

```
$(".baz").click(function() {
    alert("test: " + $(this).siblings(".bar").eq(0).text());
});
```

OR (WORSE), just for reference, never use it :)

```
$(".baz").click(function() {
    var text = 0;
    $(this).siblings(".bar").each(function(){ text = $(this).text(); break; });
    alert("test: " + text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which is useful to learn about select a siblings element in Jquery.

[How to select only one sibling with jQuery](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/Traversing-in-Jquery.aspx?id=50)

```
$("selector").nextAll(); 
$("selector").prev();
```

you can also find an element using Jquery selector

```
$("h2").siblings('table').find('tr');
```

For more information, refer this link [next(), nextAll(), prev(), prevAll(), find() and siblings in JQuery](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/Traversing-in-Jquery.aspx?id=50)